# Birth and Death Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Airline passengers must pass through a security check point consisting of a metal detector and carry on luggage X Ray machine. Suppose that passengers arrive according to a Poisson process with a rate ω = 20 passengers per minute. The Security check point clears customers at a rate of ¥ = 22. 
I am asked to find the number of customers waiting in line to be checked.
I know for Poisson process the mean is lambda( which I think in the question is given by ω= 20) i am thinking the expected number to be same as 20, but will this be correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The number of customers waiting is a random variable, likely you are asked to find the (steady state) _expected_ number of customers in an M/M/1 queue with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ with $\lambda = 20, \mu=22$.